# how return first and second item in object map function?

Tags: javascript, object, maps

i wonder how eg console.log just first and second item in object map function ?

here is in my data.Search have 10 items.

when i try to console.log 0,1 indexed items it returns me same item 10 times

```
Object.keys(data.Search).map(function (key, index) { 
    console.log(data.Search[0,1]);
});
```

Comment: `var keys = Object.keys(data.Search); console.log(data.Search[keys[0]]); console.log(data.Search[keys[keys.length-1]]);`

Comment: You have to understand that you are in the for loop of map it always out 10 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.map` isn't appropriate in that situation because you're not trying to create another array, so it appears - if you only want to cause side-effects, such as log to the console., then use generic iteration instead, with `forEach`. Test the current index (the `index` variable) to see if it's less than 2:

```
Object.keys(data.Search).forEach((key, index) => {
  if (index < 2) console.log(data.Search[key]);
});
```

Another option would be to `slice` the array of keys beforehand:

```
Object.keys(data.Search).slice(0, 2).forEach((key) => {
  console.log(data.Search[key]);
});
```

If you're interested in the *values* in the object and not the keys specifically, as it looks like might be the case, then use `Object.values`:

```
Object.values(data.Search).slice(0, 2).forEach((value) => {
  console.log(value);
});
```